# how do I find the appropriate loss function coefficients in a deep network?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loss-function

I have a deep network and it has two inputs and also two outputs. my loss function has two parts for each output `(Loss=aL1+bL2)`. I need to find suitable coefficients for each part. but I do not know how can I do an automatic full search for finding the best coefficients. do we have any function or something like this in python to do this? is `GridSearchCV` suitable for this? please help me with this issue. because I want to consider different values for each coefficient, it will be lots of situations that I have to consider. is it any solution for this?